# React.js: how to make inline styles automatically update progress bar on state change

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, reactjs

I have a progress bar that I am building in React.js and Zurb Foundation that I would like to reflect the current state.  I understand that in the beginning I can set the width with something like this:

```
render: function() {
    var spanPercent = (this.props.a - this.props.b)/this.props.a + '%';
    var spanStyle = {
        width: spanPercent
    };
    return (
        <div className="progress">
            <span className="meter" style={spanStyle}></span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

however, when the value of props changes due to a state change, the inline style doesn't update even though the props value changes.  Is there a best practice for doing this, such as using a callback, or placing the code somewhere else?  I would appreciate any help!

Comment: "when the value of props changes due to a state change" --- what does this actually mean?

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say that the data from the database from which this.props.a gets set changes.  I will also optimistically update the value of this.props.a before the ajax call comes back

Comment: Normally you can subscribe for those changes and use `setState` to change the state.

Comment: I am using setState, and this does update the value of this.props.a, and this change is reflected when I just display the value elsewhere in the component, but it's not updating the style, not sure why this might not be happening?

Comment: Your style does not depend on state, but on `props`. The state is in `this.state`

Comment: @zekms Yes, I see now what you mean.  The problem was that I was not referencing the data model properly.  I was using this.props.a instead of this.props.dataModel.a.  Now it is working, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @zerkms, no he cannot. He cannot set a state for a child if DB data comes in parent component and parent component sends `props` to a child. He cannot set `state` equal to `props`. These states break the rule of one true origin. That state of a child will never change on parant's `setState` call

Answer (score 9):

One solution is to put a key of the percentage on the element you want to update. That way when react checks to see what in the DOM has changed it sees that the key has changed and thus will rebuild the DOM for the element.

See example below:

```
render: function() {
   var spanPercent = (this.props.a - this.props.b)/this.props.a + '%';
   var spanStyle = {
          width: spanPercent
       };
   return (
      <div className="progress">
        <span key={spanPercent} className="meter" style={spanStyle}></span>
      </div>
);
```

}

Comment: Does React not check for style attribute changes in it's DOM diff algo or something? This answer works for me, but I'm still left confused as to why  this behavior is present.

Comment: @ccnokes I agree. They seem to dissuade you from "manually updating" but then you get weird results like this that makes you distrust the framework.